# HX711 module VCC and no VDD

Tags: power-supply, esp8266, nodemcu, vcc, esp32

[image: wiring diagram]

(Image source and more details: [circuitio.io](https://www.circuito.io/static/reply/index.html?solutionId=5da6ee4a9cfabe003054245f&solutionPath=storage.circuito.io))

I am trying to build the above circuit powered by battery alone. Sparkfun [HX711](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide) is expensive and hence I am using [HX711](https://www.amazon.in/Generic-HX711-Weighing-Dual-Channel-Precision/dp/B00OUZCS2Y) bought on Amazon. Here is the [documentation](https://www.sunrom.com/p/loadcell-sensor-24-bit-adc-hx711)

HX711 module has Operating Voltage: 2.7V to 5VDC and Operating current: <10 mA

Sparkfun HX711 has VCC and VDD.

> VCC is the analog voltage to power the load cell. VDD is the digital supply voltage used to set the logic level.
>   [...]
>   In many cases, you can just short VCC and VDD together. If your microcontroller uses 3.3V logic however, you'll want to connect VCC to 5V and VDD to 3.3V.

(Source: [SparkFun - Load Cell Amplifier HX711 Breakout Hookup Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide))

Amazon HX711 has only VCC and no VDD. Therefore, can I connect LoadCellHX711SF VCC to NodeMCU1 3V3 instead of connecting LoadCellHX711SF VDD to NodeMCU1 3V3?

Comment: Note that you have posted a *wiring* diagram. A schematic diagram (where each component is represented by a symbol with pin names) is much more useful and what we prefer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this "no name" module in 3V3 without problem. You can safely connect VCC to 3V3. Heere is [the reverse](https://easyeda.com/adamfk/hx711-module) to compare to the [HX711 datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf)

[image]